# MySqlCommand Timeout property not working in proper way in c#

Tags: c#, mysql

Im using mysqldatabase and successfully created storedprocedure in it.I want to call that stored procedure in my c# code.But when i'm calling mysqlcommand, timeout property is automatically set to zero.

I read that the default value is 30.I've tried to reset the timeout property in both c# code and in connection string.But I'm getting error as 'Specified method is not supported'.

What is the reason for this?? Is there any problem in having timeout value zero??

Comment: Can you provide your code? The default should be 30 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the source code (mysql driver for .net):

```
#if !CF
        //[Category("Misc")]
        //[Description("Time to wait for command to execute")]
        //[DefaultValue(30)]
#endif
        public override int CommandTimeout
        {
            get { return useDefaultTimeout ? 30 : commandTimeout; }
            set 
            {
                if (commandTimeout < 0)
                    throw new ArgumentException("Command timeout must not be negative");

                // Timeout in milliseconds should not exceed maximum for 32 bit
                // signed integer (~24 days), because underlying driver (and streams)
                // use milliseconds expressed ints for timeout values.
                // Hence, truncate the value.
                int timeout = Math.Min(value, Int32.MaxValue / 1000);
                if (timeout != value)
                {
                    MySqlTrace.LogWarning(connection.ServerThread,
                    "Command timeout value too large ("
                    + value + " seconds). Changed to max. possible value (" 
                    + timeout + " seconds)");
                }
                commandTimeout = timeout;
                useDefaultTimeout = false;
            }
        }
```